# How can send http post request using Almofire with http header .and authentication?

Tags: post, parameters, http-headers

These are my input

1.parameters

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["username ": "Henry","password":"xxxx","key"="ewq2356"]
```

2.http header

```
let headers = [ "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ]
```

3.Authentication with URLCredential

```
let user = "user1" let password = "password1"
```

4.URL

```
http://myapi.com/rest/index.php
```

So how could I use it using Almofire http post method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample api ->

```
func someFunction()
{

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "apiName",
        parameters:["Key":"Value"],
        headers: ["Content-type application":"json"])
        .authenticate(user: "userName", password: "Password")
        .response { request, response, data, error in
            if error == nil {
                print(request)
                print(response)
            }
            else {
                //Display Error Message
                print(error)
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: OK .So when I am checking it at post man by putting parameters in form data body and header in header field before that it asking for login in URL untentication what I have mentioned in my question           Authentication with URLCredential

let user = "user1" let password = "password1"

Comment: Almofire says     HTTP Basic Authentication

The authenticate method on a Request will automatically provide a URLCredential to a URLAuthenticationChallenge when appropriate:

let user = "user"
let password = "password"

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/\(user)/\(password)")
    .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }

Comment: Is that user and password a part of HTTP Auth, or simple parameters?

Comment: Http auto .For example we are using post man to check the response before that it asks for user authentication for specific URL

Comment: Yes ...It might be the answer what I was looking for